# HTML Label "FOR" can only refer "ID"?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Ok I have a Html element like this

```
<input type="button" id="harhar"/><label for="harhar">Im only for Id</label>
```

Is it possible that i can refer a label to a element not using id but a class? like this one

```
<input type="button" class="harhar"/><label for="harhar">Refer me as a class</label>
```

is this possible?

**NOTE: this is for the sake of creating dynamic Jquery UI buttons in the server-side**, that is why I want this to refer a class

Comment: How does creating the buttons server-side prevent you from adding an ID to them?

Comment: the dynamic elements came from a external source which i cannot control... hmm what i did is the answer of @jmort253 hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to match a class and a for together. However, there are things that you can do to ensure that your id's and for's are uniquely different from other for and id attributes.

When you generate your elements on the server-side, use a for loop or some other looping construct to enumerate your id/for attributes.

```
<input type="button" id="harhar_1"/><label for="harhar_1">Im only for Id</label>
<input type="button" id="harhar_2"/><label for="harhar_2">Im only for Id</label>
<input type="button" id="harhar_3"/><label for="harhar_3">Im only for Id</label>
```

If you can generate your HTML as such, then you'll be able to match up your labels and values while still using unique ids.

Additionally, there is nothing preventing you from still applying a common classname to all of your elements so that you can still easily refer to them with CSS or selectors:

```
<input class="harhar" type="button" id="harhar_1"/><label for="harhar_1">Im only for Id</label>
<input class="harhar" type="button" id="harhar_2"/><label for="harhar_2">Im only for Id</label>
<input class="harhar" type="button" id="harhar_3"/><label for="harhar_3">Im only for Id</label>
```

This provides you with the hooks that you need to write succinct CSS rules or manipulate the DOM quickly and easily.

Comment: I created a random string generator function just to append extra characters... hehe i can do something like that but not numbers... in my real code its really suffixed with numbers

Answer (score 2):

No, a label always refers to an ID, because only ID is required to be unique in the document, which is exactly what a label needs.

You will have to fall back to creating buttons with predictable, if dynamic, IDs.

Comment: @Mahan: you can write your code in a way so that you will know what the ID of the button will be, which shouldn't be a big problem. If you're using ASP.NET Webforms, where IDs are generated for you, you can can try setting `ClientIDMode` to `static` or `predictable`, or access the button's `ClientID` property to pass as a reference to the script. If you're not using Webforms, I don't suspect this should be a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

according to the [html specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) you must use the element id in the `for` attribute.
However, the specification also states that

> When [for attribute is] absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.

So, you might be able to associate the label the the input by re-arranging your html code.

Answer (score 1):

As per the specs label for must match an ID.

A workaround is making the label wrap the element it targets. It doesn't work best with screen readers etc though (you can use the same text as `title` attribute of the input element).

```
<label><input type="button" title="I am the same label" />
     I know change how this's styled...</label>
```